# Binding Input to Value of Button Click Function

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have an HTML user interface that uses Bootstrap, and has a dropmenu as well as some input fields. What I want to be able to do is populate the input field with the value of the drop-menu selection. So far I haven't been able to bind to that value and have it show up in the input value field.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="create-job-pane">
        <div class="container">
          <h2>Create Job</h2>
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
              Select Job Type to Schedule
              <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li>
                <a href="#"><button onclick="populateJobVal('option1')" class="btn btn-link">Option #1</button></a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#"><button onclick="populateJobVal('option2')" class="btn btn-link">Option #2</button></a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#"><button onclick="populateJobVal('option3')" class="btn btn-link">Option #3</button></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr />

        <!-- <p id="selection"></p> --> // Works if I populate it here

        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Job name</label>
          <input type="text" class="job-name form-control"> // Bind value here
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <span class="btn btn-default btn-success" data-action="save">Save</span>
          <span class="btn btn-default btn-warning" data-action="cancel">Cancel</span>
        </div>
      </div>

  // ... other code

  <script>
    function populateJobVal(val) {
      document.getElementById("selection").innerHTML = val;
    }

  </script>
```

I tried this:

```
 <input type="text" class="job-name form-control" value="selection">
```

And this:

```
 <input type="text" class="job-name form-control" id="selection">
```

... but it did not bind to the input field.

How can I get the value selected when my button is clicked to appear in the input text box?

Comment: You were on the right track to set the ID to `selection`. All you gotta do is change this `document.getElementById("selection").innerHTML = val;` to this: `document.getElementById("selection").value = val;`. Example: https://codepen.io/iskandarreza/pen/xxxWrGx

Comment: Ah, yes! Thanks, @IskandarRezaRazali. If you want to add this as an answer I'll mark it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just swap the `innerHTML` to `value` and you're good to go.

```js
function populateJobVal(val) {
  console.log(val);
  document.getElementById("selection").value = val;
}
```

```html
<div id="create-job-pane">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Create Job</h2>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    Select Job Type to Schedule
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><button onclick="populateJobVal('option1')" class="btn btn-link">Option #1</button></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><button onclick="populateJobVal('option2')" class="btn btn-link">Option #2</button></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><button onclick="populateJobVal('option3')" class="btn btn-link">Option #3</button></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Job name</label>
            <input type="text" class="job-name form-control" id="selection"> // Bind value here
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <span class="btn btn-default btn-success" data-action="save">Save</span>
            <span class="btn btn-default btn-warning" data-action="cancel">Cancel</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```